# How to loop and return XML values with multiple identical tags?

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I need to return the Fund_code values in the following XML. There are two Fund/Fund_code and my query is giving me an error(Given XPath points to more than one node) and I don't know how to get around it.

```
<ROWSET>
    <Fund>
        <Fund_code>F22</Fund_code>
    </Fund>
    <Fund>
        <Fund_code>F02</Fund_code>
    </Fund>
</ROWSET>
```

I tried looping through the XML elements but it wouldn't allow me.

```
FOR I IN 1..2
  loop
  SELECT COUNT(EXTRACTVALUE(V_XML, '//Fund/Fund_code'))
  INTO V_fund_code
  FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GRANT_COUNT|'||V_fund_code);
  end loop;
END;
```

It gives me this error:

```
ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node
ORA-06512: at line 34
19025. 00000 -  "EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node"
*Cause:    Given XPath points to more than one node.
*Action:   Rewrite the query so that exactly one node is returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using the following.

```
FOR I IN 1..2
  loop
  SELECT COUNT(EXTRACTVALUE(V_XML, '//Fund['||I||']/Fund_code'))
  INTO V_fund_code
  FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GRANT_COUNT|'||V_fund_code);
  end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  FOR i in (
             SELECT Fund_code
                FROM 
                   xmltable(
                              '//Fund'
                              PASSING XMLTYPE('<ROWSET>
                                                    <Fund>
                                                        <Fund_code>F22</Fund_code>
                                                    </Fund>
                                                    <Fund>
                                                        <Fund_code>F02</Fund_code>
                                                    </Fund>
                                                </ROWSET>')
                             COLUMNS
                                Fund_code varchar2(10) PATH '//*:Fund_code'                      
                                )

                           ) LOOP

               dbms_output.put_line(i.fund_code);

   END LOOP;
END;
```